# Exceptions in .dockerignore

Tags: docker

How does `.dockerignore` handle exceptions?

For example, I would like to ignore everything from the `src/` directory except for `src/web/public`.

I've tried...

```
.git
src
!src/web/public
```

Seems to not work.

`docker build .` shows `Sending build context to Docker daemon 20.63 MB` either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not appear that `.dockerignore` handles exceptions. If there is a well-known syntax for this, [you could propose the change and make a pull request](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

In [tag 1.3 of commands.go](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/c78088fe3d1b90640c637d8c3457de3caa0c7a24/api/client/commands.go#L160) we see this:

```
    ignore, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path.Join(root, ".dockerignore"))
    // ...
    options := &archive.TarOptions{
        Compression: archive.Uncompressed,
        Excludes:    excludes,
    }
    context, err = archive.TarWithOptions(root, options)
```

and in [archive.go](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/4424d15f9936a6cf663d06284c932f91306d9353/pkg/archive/archive.go#L374):

```
    for _, include := range options.Includes {

            // ...
            skip, err := fileutils.Matches(relFilePath, options.Excludes)
            if err != nil {
                log.Debugf("Error matching %s", relFilePath, err)
                return err
            }

            if skip {
                if f.IsDir() {
                    return filepath.SkipDir
                }
                return nil
            }
            // ...
    }
```

Comment: a message from the future: it is now possible to have exceptions. Please see the answers below :)

Answer (score 30):

Just wanted to add in case others run into this question, that
from docker 1.7.0 exclusions are supported in the .dockerignore file. So the example `!src/web/public` in the question actually works

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file

Answer (score 5):

Using my response to another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/51429852/2419069 you can use the following `.dockerignore` file:

```
# Ignore everything
**

# Allow /src/web/public directory
!/src/web/public/**

# You can also ignore unnecessary files inside the /src/web/public to make your image even smaller.
**/*~
**/*.log
**/.DS_Store
**/Thumbs.db
```