# is there a way to negate a pattern in .dockerignore?

Tags: docker

I am trying to negate a pattern in a .dockerignore.  The Globbing is done using Go's filepath.Match rules. After checking the [source](http://golang.org/src/pkg/path/filepath/match.go), it seems we can negate a pattern by using ^ character.

.dockerfile

```
*
^Dockerfile
^web-app/dist
```

However, when i docker build, I have the following error:

```
Dockerfile was excluded by .dockerignore pattern '*'
```

Do you know if its possible to accomplish what I want ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exceptions in .dockerignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636566/exceptions-in-dockerignore)

Comment: the `*` will match everything, making the other patterns irrelevant. I'm also trying to find a way to negate a string, from the docs it looks like `^` only applies to character ranges, eg `[^_]*` to match everything that doesn't start with a `_`

Comment: not a duplicate, in my opinion

Answer (score 30):

As of version [1.7.0](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#170-2015-06-16), this is now possible.

Negating with `!` now works as you would expect and is documented in the official [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file).

Here's an example taken from the link above:

```
*/temp*
*/*/temp*
temp?
*.md
!LICENSE.md
```

The line `!LICENSE.md` will cause LICENSE.md to be included in the Docker build context despite the `*.md` rule.