# Dockerignore: Ignore everything except a file and the Dockerfile

Tags: docker

So the main intention was to dockerize a fat jar application and put it into Elasticbeanstalk. The problem is with the context. It's a little bit stupid to add so much context into docker if all I need is actually a single jar file.

I've been playing around with the .dockerignore file, but I am lost. I tried to use the gitignore negation, but it doesn't work.

```
*
!Dockerfile
*/
!target/
target/*
!target/*.jar
```

There's also that thing with regex, but it seems like complicated regex is not supported.

```
^((?!Dockerfile).)*$
```

I have also tried searching in stackoverflow, and these two are all I found:

- [Exceptions in .dockerignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636566/exceptions-in-dockerignore)
- [is there a way to negate a pattern in .dockerignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26776269/is-there-a-way-to-negate-a-pattern-in-dockerignore)

This question might be similiar to the second one, but I think it's slightly difference since in here, I just want to include a single file into the context.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Exclamation mark for folders works for me!

Answer (score 273):

If you need to ignore everything except some directories or files and also ignore some unnecessary files inside those allowed directories you can use the following `.dockerignore` file:

```
# Ignore everything
*

# Allow files and directories
!/file.txt
!/src

# Ignore unnecessary files inside allowed directories
# This should go after the allowed directories
**/*~
**/*.log
**/.DS_Store
**/Thumbs.db
```

Comment: According to [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) it should be sufficient to put only `*` on the first line (instead of `**`). Quote: "you may want to specify which files to include in the context, rather than which to exclude. To achieve this, specify `*` as the first pattern, followed by one or more `!` exception patterns".

Comment: Why `!/src/**` and not `!/src`?

Answer (score 40):

From the [dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/dockerignore-file):

> Beyond Go’s filepath.Match rules, Docker also supports a special wildcard string ** that matches any number of directories (including zero). For example, **/*.go will exclude all files that end with .go that are found in all directories, including the root of the build context.

So a line containing simply ** will ignore everything in the same directory as the Dockerfile.

As expected the exclamation can then be used to reference any files you do wish to send to the docker daemon.

Comment: It's extremely important that the `**` goes to the top of the file, otherwise the exclusions will be ignored. Docker uses the last rule that matches as the "final" rule, so if `**` is last it'll match everything.

Comment: So add `**` on the first line and `!foo` on the next line if `foo` is the only file you want to include.

Comment: "So a line containing simply ** will ignore everything in the same directory as the Dockerfile" to be exact, it will ignore everything in the context directory, which might be different from where Dockerfile is located

Answer (score 10):

This may sound strange, but if all you need is a single jar file,  you could create a "docker" folder in your build system that contains your Dockerfile.  When you run your builds, have the build scripts copy the single jar file into "docker" then execute the docker image build (from inside the "docker" folder) and push to your docker registry when done.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't sound strange at all. I thought it was a general practice, but I was looking for a way to do it with the .dockerignore if possible. Besides, I don't really like mvn xml :)

Comment: You can combine both approaches by putting the dockerfile in a subdirectory and use .dockerignore. According to the docs, it is good to do so anyways

Comment: [Docker's documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#usage):

In most cases, it’s best to start with an empty directory as context and keep your Dockerfile in that directory. Add only the files needed for building the Dockerfile.

Warning: Do not use your root directory, /, as the PATH as it causes the build to transfer the entire contents of your hard drive to the Docker daemon.

Answer (score -1):

Here a sample file that can be used for `.dockerignore`

```
# Git
.git
.gitignore
.gitattributes


# CI
.codeclimate.yml
.travis.yml
.taskcluster.yml

# Docker
.docker
.dockerignore

# Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
**/__pycache__/
**/*.py[cod]

# C extensions
*.so

# Distribution / packaging
.Python
env/
build/
develop-eggs/
dist/
downloads/
eggs/
lib/
lib64/
parts/
sdist/
var/
*.egg-info/
.installed.cfg
*.egg

# PyInstaller
#  Usually these files are written by a python script from a template
#  before PyInstaller builds the exe, so as to inject date/other infos into it.
*.manifest
*.spec

# Installer logs
pip-log.txt
pip-delete-this-directory.txt

# Unit test / coverage reports
htmlcov/
.tox/
.coverage
.cache
nosetests.xml
coverage.xml

# Translations
*.mo
*.pot

# Django stuff:
*.log

# Sphinx documentation
docs/_build/

# PyBuilder
target/

# Virtual environment
.venv/
venv/

# PyCharm
.idea

# Python mode for VIM
.ropeproject
**/.ropeproject

# Vim swap files
**/*.swp

# VS Code
.vscode/

*.log
```