# Is is possible to use .dockerignore to make docker build really ignore everything?

Tags: docker

**OS Version/build:** macOS High Sierra 10.13 (17A365) - Docker version 17.10.0-ce, build f4ffd25

Having a folder with 1.4GB and **no .dockerignore** file, build takes a very long time to start and I get this message:

```
> time docker build -t continous-testing-dashboard .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.416GB  
...
5.23s user 11.88s system 45% cpu 37.795 total
```

Total time: **37 seconds**

Adding (pretty much) all folders to a .dockerignore file

```
.git
.idea
app
bootstrap
config
database
node_modules
public
resources
storage
tests
vendor
```

It still takes a lot of time and sends a big context do Deamon:

```
> time docker build -t continous-testing-dashboard .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  675.3MB
...
17.81s user 6.78s system 86% cpu 28.439 total
```

Total time: **28 seconds**

But building the very same Dockerfile on an empty folder I get:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  32.26kB
0.03s user 0.03s system 25% cpu 0.230 total
```

Total time: **230 milliseconds!!**

Looks like it's ignoring nothing, and still adding ~1/3 of the files to the context. Is there a way to make it really ignore everyhing?

Comment: it looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097064/dockerignore-ignore-everything-except-a-file-and-the-dockerfile is relevant to your question: use `**` to ignore everything in the same directory as your ignore file

Comment: Ignoring everything is not an option, but I figured out myself what the other answer tells: adding a folder with the Dockerfile and some other files fix this, but as I have to reference that folder in docker run, I still think there might be a way to fix this behaviour

Comment: If you don't need the larger folder as part of the `docker build`, but only as part of the `docker run`, you can also look at using a volume with `docker run -v /path/on/my_computer:/path/inside/container image:tag`

Comment: I think that the problem is that `.dockerignore` is evaluated on the docker daemon. So it first sends *ALL* of the data from your build folder to the daemon and than filters out the ignored ones.