# .dockerignore - exclude directory except certain file-types

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerignore

I have a `.dockerignore` file in which I want to exclude the entire directory `/src` except all `.json` files in that `/src`-Directory.

My current approach looks like this:

```
/src/*
!/src/**/*.json
```

I have also tried using `/src` instead of `/src/*`, but in both cases is the entire directory excluded and the JSON files are nowhere to be found.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dockerignore: Ignore everything except a file and the Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097064/dockerignore-ignore-everything-except-a-file-and-the-dockerfile)

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I have now also tried `/src/**` but still no correct result.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the ignore file as follow:

```
/src/*
!/src/*.json
!/src/**/*.json
```

The reason is that `!/src/**/*.json` searches for json files inside subfolder of `/src`, and not in `/src` itself too.

Look at the official documentation if you need further info https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file .

Comment: This does not seem to work (there are no files that match `/src/*.json` anyway). But I have no clue what is wrong. It looks like it should work.