# Directory incorrectly being ignored in .dockerignore

Tags: docker

I am trying to make Docker ignore the `data/` folder at the root of my project, but also to include an exception for the `src/data` folder, which is not to be ignored. However, no matter what I do, `src/data` is always ignored.

I tried to follow the examples shown in the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) and [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636566/exceptions-in-dockerignore) but I must be misunderstanding something because the following `.dockerignore` exception is not working for me; both `data/` and `src/data` are ignored, but I want `src/data` to be included in the docker image:

```
# .dockerignore
data
!src/data
```

The relevant `Dockerfile` `COPY` statement:

```
# Dockerfile
COPY . ./
```

This only occurs when deploying to Google Cloud; locally, `src/data` is included, although I use the Google Cloud CLI for both. So this makes me wonder if there is a different version of Docker on Google Cloud, because the syntax of `.dockerignore` has changed throughout the years.

The obvious workaround would just be to rename `src/data` to something else. But I want to understand what's going on.